# convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{\frac {1}{n}} \dfrac {\sqrt x}{1+x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Test convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{\frac {1}{n}} \dfrac {\sqrt x}{1+x^2} dx$

**Attempt:** Since, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac {1}{n} \in (0,1) \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{\frac {1}{n}} \dfrac {\sqrt x}{1+x^2} dx \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{\frac {1}{n}} \dfrac { x}{1+x^2} dx$

If $I = \int_0^{\frac {1}{n}} \dfrac { x}{1+x^2} dx = \dfrac {1}{2} \ln (1+ \dfrac {1}{n^2})$

Now, for $\ln (1+\dfrac {1}{n^2}) <(1+\dfrac {1}{n^2})$

Since, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1+\dfrac {1}{n^2})$ is convergent $\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty   \ln (1+\dfrac {1}{n^2})$ is convergent as well.

But, I don't think this result is of any use as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{\frac {1}{n}} \dfrac {\sqrt x}{1+x^2} dx \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{\frac {1}{n}} \dfrac { x}{1+x^2} dx$

Please guide me on moving from here.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that the denominator is there just to confuse you. For sufficiently small $x$,
$$1\ge\frac1{1+x^2}\ge\frac12,$$
so we can disregard that altogether. Now
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^{1/n}\sqrt x\,dx=\frac23\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^{3/2}},$$
which converges.

Comment: The lower bound $0$ is sufficient (instead of $\frac12$), and the upper bound $1$ holds for every $x$ (small or not).

Answer (score -1):

Note that:
$$\int_0^{1/n}\frac{\sqrt x}{1+x^2} dx \sim\int_0^{1/n}\sqrt x dx \quad \text{as} \quad n\to+\infty$$
Hence, by the comparison test, you have:
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\int_0^{1/n}\frac{\sqrt x}{1+x^2} dx \sim \sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$
and the last series converges.

Comment: why the downvote?